# How to install and run Laravel project in different PC

Tags: php, laravel

Good day to all, I am new to Laravel and recently I was given a test task on the accomplishment of which I could be hired as a Laravel programmer. So, somehow I could complete a project and then sent it employer. Later, the employer asked me to send instructions on how to install and run my created test project on his PC. Now I wonder what kind of info and instructions can be sent to him so that he could successfully run my project. I know guys this question can be a bit wierd but I hope you guys can rescue me.

Comment: @B001ᛦ, Thank you for your attention, believe it or not but he doesn't want to do anything all he wants is just instructions on how to run and that's it. Wierd I know:)

Comment: Follow the documentation for Laravel , and practice

Comment: After installing the [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) on his system, he needs to run `composer install` from his project root which will install everything. To run/use the app, he need a web server. Also, he needs to run the migrations/seeds for preparing the database.

Comment: @TheAlpha, hi dude, please if it is ok for can you  help me with instructions. Just what instructions would you send to him if you were me. Thank you dude in advance :)

Comment: Does he has the Laravel environment on his PC? He was to start only  your app? Or he needs to install everything? Also, How did you sent the project? You have it in a repository?

Comment: If he just want to check your project, the better way is to use a repository like github and after this you can deploy your application to a platform like Heroku. In this way he doesn't need to spend hours when installing Laravel's environment.

Answer (score 1):

If he follows the installation instructions from the Laravel [website](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2) he could then copy your project into the Laravel installation.

**Instructions from Laravel documentation:**

**Install Composer**

Laravel utilizes Composer to manage its dependencies. First, download a copy of the  composer.phar. Once you have the PHAR archive, you can either keep it in your local project directory or move to usr/local/bin to use it globally on your system. On Windows, you can use the Composer Windows installer.

**Via Laravel Installer**

First, download the Laravel installer using Composer.

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

Make sure to place the ~/.composer/vendor/bin directory in your PATH so the laravel executable is found when you run the laravel command in your terminal.

Once installed, the simple laravel new command will create a fresh Laravel installation in the directory you specify. For instance, laravel new blog would create a directory named blog containing a fresh Laravel installation with all dependencies installed. This method of installation is much faster than installing via Composer.

**Via Composer Create-Project**

You may also install Laravel by issuing the Composer create-project command in your terminal:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory} 4.2 --prefer-dist
```

**Via Download**

Once Composer is installed, download the 4.2 version of the Laravel framework and extract its contents into a directory on your server. Next, in the root of your Laravel application, run the php composer.phar install (or composer install) command to install all of the framework's dependencies. This process requires Git to be installed on the server to successfully complete the installation.

**Configuration**

The first thing you should do after installing Laravel is set your application key to a random string. If you installed Laravel via Composer, this key has probably already been set for you by the key:generate command. Typically, this string should be 32 characters long. The key can be set in the app.php configuration file. If the application key is not set, your user sessions and other encrypted data will not be secure.

Laravel needs almost no other configuration out of the box. You are free to get started developing! However, you may wish to review the app/config/app.php file and its documentation. It contains several options such as timezone and locale that you may wish to change according to your application.

Comment: better do it fast because your answer came to deletion queue of posts, other moderator may give delete flags to your answer. please include description to your answer to avoid deletion

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps and install the laravel project on your local machine.

=> first install composer in the system

**=> Install composer tool**

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

**=> after install laravel project**

composer create-project laravel/laravel test

```
or
```

composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
    or (Version vise)

composer create-project laravel/laravel blog "5.1.*"

**=> for run laravel project**

```
php artisan serv
```

**=> For How to create Migration in Laravel5**

-> Create tabel for migration

```
php artisan make:migration create_books_table
```

-> Run Migration

php artisan migrate

-> For new new migration run

```
php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/planmigration/
```

-> Create Model

```
php artisan make:model User
```

-> Run Seeder

php artisan db:seed

Comment: `composer create-project laravel/laravel test` will create a new project but he needs to run an existing project. All he needs to run the `composer install` from the project root to install the dependencies and migrations/seeding and a working web server.

Comment: @Saurabh Dhariwal, hey dude sorry but Does he really need to create new Laravel  project since he needs to run my already created project

Comment: This is not relevant to the question. He is not asking how to create a new project. He is asking how to run an existing project on another computer / server.

Comment: @Mirich I was sent you general guidance. Exiting project setup is also like this and you have to perform all dependency for the project. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If It's a regular Laravel project, then they would need

- [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/)
- [node.js/npm](https://nodejs.org/en/) (if used within the project - it comes out the box for webpack and laravel mix)

You should send him your project, without the `vendor` and `node_modules` folder. Then when he receives the project, he should go to the folder via his command prompt and type `composer install` followed by `npm install`.

When they are done installing all the dependencies, then he needs to create a `.env` file in the root folder of the project and fill it out with the relevant information, such as his database information. (It's good practice that you include an example file like `.env.example` that comes with Laravel by default.)

Then when his `.env` file is setup correctly with the right information then he needs to run `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` (This will dump the database and migrate all your migrations from scratch, aswell as run all your seeders)

Now the application should be ready.